Objectbox triggers/webhooks
Has objectbox server an option to send trigger/webhook to an api?
we are using c# backend, so there is no client and we would need to process data to i.e. send email.
App has local objectbox db.
Backend has its own objectbox db.
App DB and Backend DB gets synchronized.
Backend DB needs to trigger a url (with data), so that backend can send email to someone (based on that data).
OR
dotnet core api can listen for changed in objectbox db (its own) and send emails.

The question lacks details; please describe what you want to do and where (client, backend, obx server).
